# jquery slider hide .prev button when first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I hide the button .prev when this is first? 
and why the slider goes back to first slide when is last clicking .prev? how can I fix this?

```
    var nextPane = function (e) {
        e && e.preventDefault();
        var $container = $(this).closest('.grid-container');
        var $items = $('.items', $container);
        var offset = $items.css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
        var width = $container.width() + parseInt($('.item', $container).css('marginRight').replace('px', ''));
        $items.css('marginLeft', offset - width);

        if($(this).parent().find('.items').width() + (offset - width) < width){
            $(this).hide();
        }

    }

    var prevPane = function (e) {
        e && e.preventDefault();
        var $container = $(this).closest('.grid-container');
        var $items = $('.items', $container);
        var offset = $items.css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
        var width = $container.width() + parseInt($('.item', $container).css('marginRight').replace('px', '')); 
        $items.css('marginLeft', offset + width);


        if($('.next').is( ":hidden" )){
            $(this).parent().find('.next').show();
        }
    }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tUZ4/5/)

Comment: God... How do you control, *at all*, which slide are you viewing? Besides, you're getting references to all your jQuery objects every time one of the buttons are clicked. Why don't you store external references to them?

Comment: @Oscar Paz thanks, could you help me with this please?

Comment: Well, I'm having difficulties understanding what you do, as you don't provide markup and CSS. How do you know which slide are you viewing? I suggest you to provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: MAte, yes I provide all its on my question my code:-) http://jsfiddle.net/2tUZ4/5/

Comment: @Oscar Paz  are u able to give me a hand?

Comment: A little detail: The `.replace()` in `parseInt($('.item', $container).css('marginRight').replace('px', ''));` is useless. `parseInt()` will take the first numeric value it finds, and ignore the 'px' anyway.

Comment: @Skwal thanks, for looking into this. could u put it into fiddle please?

Comment: @Skwal like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yfMFd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not going back one slide, but are always returning to the first slide on prev, you can just `hide()` and `show()` the prev when you click next or previous.

When clicking next

```
$(this).parent().find('.prev').show();
```

When clicking previous

```
$(this).parent().find('.prev').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2tUZ4/8/

Comment: thanks, good job! how can I prevent on the last slide if I click prev to go back to the first one?

Comment: So you don't want to go back to the first slide when clicking prev? If so then this fix is no good.

Comment: I wan to hide the prev on first slide but also when I'm on the last slide if I click prev, than I should be able to the previous one not the first one., does it makes sense?